# Newton's Law of Cooling/Exponential Growth and Decay Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on this problem and I need help determining what to do.

**Question:**

Suppose that $f'(x) = 5f(x) - 10$ and $f(0) = 5$. Find $f(x)$.

**My reasoning:**

Since, $f'(x) = 5f(x) - 10$, we can say:

$$f'(x) + 10 = 5f(x) \Longrightarrow f(x) = \frac{1}{5} f'(x) + 2$$

$$f(0) = \frac{1}{5} f'(0) + 2 = 5$$
$$\frac{1}{5} f'(0) = 3 \Longrightarrow f'(0) = 15$$

$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f'(x)dx = \frac{1}{5} f'(x) + 2$$

$$f(x) - f(0) = \frac{1}{5} f'(x) + 2$$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{5} f'(x) + 7.$$

But this is not the correct answer. Somehow, I have to use Newton's Law of Cooling or Decay. I am not sure how to do that. Can anyone let me know where my reasoning is faulty or what I am not doing correctly please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use it in particular to obtain the answer.

Let $\ y = f(x) $.

Dividing both sides by $\ y-2$ and multiplying $\ dx$ on both sides, we get:

$$ \frac{dy}{y-2} = 5 \ dx $$

Integrating both sides, we get:

$$\ ln(y-2) = 5x + C $$

where C is some constant. Now, given that at x = 0, y = 5, we get:

$$\ ln(3) = C $$.

Thus, rearranging the terms, we get:

$$\ ln(\frac{y-2}{3}) = 5x $$

Or

$$\ y = f(x) = 3 \cdot e^{5x} +2 $$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I see where I went wrong.